# Regex to find SoundCloud URLs using C#/Selenium

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find SoundCloud URLs in a string. After reading SO, I've tried a few different REGEX formulas, none of which has worked.

Example URL

> https://soundcloud.com/katyperry

My regex

```
 Regex scRegex = new Regex(@"^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[\w\-\.]+(\/)+[\w\-\.]+/?$",
 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

All code for clarity

```
 string ps = driver.PageSource;
 string words = string.Join(" ", ps);
 Regex scRegex = new Regex(@"^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[\w\-\.]+(\/)+[\w\-\.]+/?$",
 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 //find items that matches with our pattern
 MatchCollection scMatches = scRegex.Matches(words);
 soundcloud = scMatches[0].ToString();
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, remove `^` and `$`. Second, escape literal dots, and do not escape `/`s. Third, what are the pattern requirements?

Comment: Updated my question :)

Comment: Try `Regex scRegex = new Regex(@"(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(m\.)?soundcloud\.com(?:/[\w.-]+)+/?");`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%28%3f%3awww%5c.%29%3f%28m%5c.%29%3fsoundcloud%5c.com%28%3f%3a%2f%5b%5cw.-%5d%2b%29%2b%2f%3f&i=https%3a%2f%2fsoundcloud.com%2fkatyperry).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove `^` and `$` since you are not validating a string, but extract from a longer text. Second, escape literal dots, and do not escape `/`s since the latter are not special regex metacharacters.

Then, use

```
Regex scRegex = new Regex(@"(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?soundcloud\.com(?:/[\w.-]+)+/?");
```

Or, with word boundary at the start:

```
Regex scRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?soundcloud\.com(?:/[\w.-]+)+/?");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3ahttps%3f%3a%2f%2f%29%3f%28%3f%3awww%5c.%29%3f%28%3f%3am%5c.%29%3fsoundcloud%5c.com%28%3f%3a%2f%5b%5cw.-%5d%2b%29%2b%2f%3f&i=https%3a%2f%2fsoundcloud.com%2fkatyperry).

**Details**

- `\b` - the char immediately before the current location must be a non-word char, or start of string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://` char sequence
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional `www.` char sequence
- `(?:m\.)?` - an optional `m.` char sequence
- `soundcloud\.com` - a `soundcloud.com` substring
- `(?:/[\w.-]+)+` - 0 or more repatitions of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `[\w.-]+`  - 1+ word, `.` or `-` chars
- `/?`  - an optional `/`.